# What is the best statistical test for percentage of respondents data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

My data consists of three columns

A is the percentage of those who answered 'Yes' on question 1
B is the percentage of those who answered 'Yes' on question 2
C is a number that represents a score. This score is an index that is NOT calculated based on the previous columns. It is kind of rating for this group.

I want to analyze the significance of the impact of answering 'Yes' in both questions on the score value. Which statistical test should I use?

here's a snippet of the data
[image]

This is the full data
[image]

Comment: Hi Lisa. It's a bit unclear to me what your data look like. For example, given that you say that column A and B represent percentages, can we assume that each row represents a group of people? If so, do you have the number of respondents for each row (instead of percentages)? Also, how is the score in column C computed? Is it some sort of average of individual scores? If so, do you have access to the individual scores? Sharing a small snippet of your data could be useful for clarifying some of these questions.

Comment: yes each row represent a group of people. yes I do have the number of those who answered yes and the number of respondents. The data in column C is kind of rating for this group of people. we want to see if answering yes to both question 1 & 2 would affect the rating in 3.

Comment: And I added a snippet

Comment: @J-J-J I added the full data set snippet

Comment: Try logistic regression with `Index`  as predictor